# install Slim3 beta with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

how can I install Slim3 beta with composer?
I tried --dev with no luck
The [official docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/installation.html) say nothing and composer search revealed nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the following command from from commandline.

```
$ composer require slim/slim:~3.0@dev
```

Another option is to create a `composer.json` with the following content.

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "~3.0@dev"
    }
}
```

After creating the file in the same folder run

```
$ composer install
```